# Dual Monitor setup only displays on second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I have an HP laptop dual-booted with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. I'm trying to use a second monitor I have while using Ubuntu but I keep having the following issues:

1. Only the second monitor appears with a screen after I click "Detect Displays" in Ubuntu Display Settings
2. I can't open the display settings or a web browser once I connect to the second monitor
3. If I disconnect my VGA cable from my laptop I lose the second screen and my main screen doesn't come back. I have to restart my laptop to get back into Ubuntu.

I don't have any fancy graphics driver that I know of in my laptop. It uses an AMD APU so idk if that would cause any issues.

EDIT:

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Trinity [Radeon HD 7640G]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:37 memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0300000-f033ffff
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please help us help you by [edit]ing further information into your post. At bare minimum I'd like to see the output of `sudo lshw -C display` which will tell us the video hardware and driver in use. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Do both screens work as expected in Windows 10?

Comment: Yep i've used the laptop with dual screens in Windows 10

Comment: @ElderGeek I've updated my question with the terminal output. Thanks!